# Why can't I disable IPv6 on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: ipv6

I have disabled IPV6 but still see traffic from my Ubuntu 17.04 machine.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1

$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf |grep ipv6

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

But in jnettop I see things like:

```
TCP6  fe80::b27f:b9ff:fe03:7d6a
ICMP6  ff02::1
```

How do I disable all IPV6 traffic?  Is support a kernel module I can disable?

(Let's not debate the merits of IPv6.)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63758/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-user665521).

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 support is built into the kernel.  I will have to compile my own.